# CORS issue in node server using heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, cors

I've researched this issue for days and I can't understand why I'm having this CORS issue when trying to request information from my server app on Heroku.  See the code below as well as a link to the git repo.  You will see I have the CORS package in JSON file under dependencies.  Do I need to update node or something? Is it a dynos issue (I barely know what dynos are and if I need them for this simple project)? Maybe a Procfile or .env issue?  I have node_modules in .gitignore but Heroku automotaically installs dependecies found in package-lock.json, right? I even used cli npm i just to be sure.  I'm stuck. Any help will be absolutely appreciated:

[git repo](https://github.com/Newbclharri/portfolio1-backend/tree/test)
server.js:

```
    ////////////////////
// DEPENDENCIES
///////////////////
require("dotenv").config();

const express = require('express'); //server framework
const cors = require('cors'); //cross origin resource sharing to access data from foreign origins

/////////////////////
// JSON FILES
////////////////////
const projects = require("./projects.json");
const about = require("./about.json");
const tutorials = require("./tutorials.json");

// Create application object
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

//////////////
// MIDDLEWARE
//////////////
app.use(cors());

//////////////
// ROUTES
//////////////

//home route for api testing
app.get("/", (req, res) =>{
    res.send("Hello World")
});

//route for retrieving projectws
app.get("/projects", (req, res)=>{
    //send projects via JSON
    res.json(projects);
});

//route for retrieving about info
app.get("/about", (req, res) =>{
    //send about via JSON
    res.json(about);
});

//route for retrieving tutorial info
app.get("/tutorials", (req, res)=>{
    //send about via JSON
    res.json(tutorials);
});

/////////////
// PORT LISTENER
////////////
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("They're listening on port", PORT));
```

Comment: You have just shown the backend, it seem like you have a Frontend issue trying to fetch data from a wrong URL (*/removed?*) when I've opened the `origin` you have provided in the GitHub repo the frontend `https://64841ff3c8f2a62fec2a1614--deluxe-gumdrop-e15f00.netlify.app` opens up, but it's trying to fetch from a `https://cj-portfolio1-backend.herokuapp.com/about` which responds with status code `503` - *server is down*. So, #1 is the URL correct? #2 is the server UP and running?

Comment: Thanks, Aleksander for the reply.  I will double-check the backend server URL but I think it's the correct one.  Also, how do I check if my server is running in Heroku?  From my understanding, the CLI command to push to Heroku locally starts the process to run the server.  Am I mistaken, how do I check if the server is running?

Also, do you need the link to the backend repo?

Comment: I found this issue.  Heroku requires a subscription for its webservices, so the server application was never running.  I switch to render.com and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue.  Heroku requires a subscription for its webservices, so the server application was never running.  I switch to render.com and it works fine now.